# undefined reference to `INTDisableInterrupts'

Tags: c++, компиляция, обработка-ошибок

Использую в mplab компилятор xc32 + библиотеки периферии путем указания "#include <plib.h>"

При компиляции возникает ошибка на несуществующий референс на некоторые системные функции, которые у меня используются в проекте, которые относятся к периферии  из plib.h и связанных библиотек, которые точно размещены в едином каталоге include в папке с компилятором.

Прошу подсказать как этого избежать. Спасибо

build/default/production/main.o: In function `SYSTEMConfig': c:/program files (x86)/microchip/xc32/v2.20/pic32mx/include/peripheral/system.h:354: undefined reference to` INTDisableInterrupts'
build/default/production/main.o: In function `SYSTEMConfigWaitStates': c:/program files (x86)/microchip/xc32/v2.20/pic32mx/include/peripheral/system.h:188: undefined reference to` INTDisableInterrupts'
c:/program files (x86)/microchip/xc32/v2.20/pic32mx/include/peripheral/system.h:190: undefined reference to `INTRestoreInterrupts'